# Как сделать бэкап из .bak файла?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, резервное-копирование, sql-server-localdb

Как выгрузить данные из database.bak в базу данных? Иcпользую ASP.NET MVC 5. Пробовал вот такой запрос:

```
BACKUP DATABASE Products TO DISK = 'C:\Backups\database.bak'
```

Пишет, что Products не существует, хотя в APP_Data она есть.

И вот так:

```
RESTORE Products 
FROM DISK = 'C:/db/database.bak'
```

Вываливается ошибка: 'Products' is not a recognized RESTORE option.

Строка подключения:

```
<add connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\database.mdf';Integrated Security=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: *как выгрузить данных из database.bak в базу данных* - наверно наоборот из СУБД в  database.bak? Если наоборот, то это будет `RESTORE`. Исправьте вопрос, не очень понятно в какую сторону что выгружается.

Comment: APP_Data в данном случае не влияет на работу этой строки, проверяйте ваш коннект, возможно вы не к тому серверу баз подсоиденились. Или не под тем логином (нет прав видеть эту базу у вашего пользователя).

Comment: Хм.. вот смотрите, в папке App_Data  я создал новую бд, и пытаюсь в нее выгрузить данные из файла database.bak

Comment: 1. Используйте RESTORE. 2. Проверяйте правильность подключения.

Comment: Пишет 'Northwind' is not a recognized RESTORE option'.

Comment: Прикрепите ваш скрипт и ошибку к вопросу

Comment: Прикрепил, можно смотреть

Comment: У вас `Products` это название базы или таблицы?

Comment: @YuriGo правильная инструкция RESTORE DATABASE [Products] FROM  DISK = N'C:/db/database.bak' + если там уже есть файлы БД без флага overwrite вы базу не поднимите. Можете посмотреть полный скрипт создав его в SSMS.

Comment: Products - это название базы. Первый раз работаю с ASP.NET MVC, подскажите правильно ли я понял, мне, в мою только что созданную базу Products.mdf, надо выгрузить данные из файла database.bak? Или восстановление данных из этого файла как то по-другому делается:

Comment: @YuriGo если она пустая, воспользуйтесь моим скриптом

Comment: База абсолютно пустая. Выполнил ваш скрипт, пишет: Msg 3154, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'Products'' database.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Почему просто не поднять БД из бекапа раз ваша пустая? Удалите свою и поднимите бэкап моим скриптом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы создали БД и хотите залить в нее данные с бэкапа, лучше воспользоваться стандартным инструментом в SSMS.

ПКМ на Databases

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В окне выберите Device. И укажите фаш файл в качестве источника.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого нажмите OK.

Таааадааааам, база поднята)

ЗЫ Это все справедливо для случая если у вас нет БД.
Если есть, и ваша БД имеет аналогичную структуру с той что в бэкапе.
Нужно добавить флаг Overwrite.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы меня совсем запутали) Вот смотрите, я создал новый проект, где мне выполнить приведенный вами SQL чтобы у меня появилась база с данными из database.bak?)

Comment: Поставьте  SSMS если у вас ее еще нет и подключитесь к локальному инстансу, вы там увидите свою БД и сможете нормально ей управлять. + сможете выполнить все что я вам выше описал.